# Azure pipeline how to install ml_service for creating env

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

how to install ml_service for importing :

```
from ml_service.utils.env_variables import Env
from ml_service.utils.manage_environment import get_environment
```

Comment: Hi, I added an answer, please check it. If I misunderstood you, could you please describe your question in more detail? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [doc](https://github.com/microsoft/MLOpsPython/blob/master/ml_service/pipelines/diabetes_regression_build_train_pipeline.py), it define the [Env](https://github.com/microsoft/MLOpsPython/blob/74885302c4f8382992b964615b0b989a74578ddc/ml_service/util/env_variables.py#L11) and [get_environment](https://github.com/microsoft/MLOpsPython/blob/74885302c4f8382992b964615b0b989a74578ddc/ml_service/util/manage_environment.py#L8) in the different .py files, then use them via

```
from ml_service.util.env_variables import Env
from ml_service.util.manage_environment import get_environment
```